# Reverse a matrix with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-inverse, bigdata

I'm a Beginner in bigdata.
I had learned Python.
I want get Reverse a matrix with tensorflow (matrix n*n in input), but office boss will to do it with tensorflow, so i wanna do it without Adjoining matrix.
help me, please.
thank you In advance. <3

Answer (score 0):

You are (probably) looking for [`tf.matrix_inverse`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matrix_inverse).

Comment: I do not know how make adjoint

Comment: @chris Just set it to `False`, or ignore it — it defaults to `False`.

Comment: computation the matrix with Faces an error
a = tf.constant([20.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,20.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,20.0], shape=[3,3],name='a') # this is my matrix

[[ 0.05023923 -0.00239234 -0.00239234]
 [-0.00239234  0.05023923 -0.00239234]
 [-0.00239234 -0.00239234  0.05023924]]
# this is output


 21/418 -1/418 -1/418
 -1/418 21/418 -1/418
 -1/418 -1/418 21/418

# this is answer

Comment: yes, first output for tensorflow , second for http://matrix.reshish.com/inverse.php

Comment: no, It makes a mistake.
The answers are not the same

Answer (score 0):

You mean you need to swap rows and columns? If that's the case then you might use tf.transpose.

Comment: ‍‍‍‍
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
# test project

import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import timeit
from numpy import *
import tensorflow as tf

def invmatrix():

    z = input()
    a = matrix('{}'.format(z))
    b = linalg.det(a)

    # compute inverse

    if b==0:
        print ("determinant is {} inverse not exist".format(b))
    else:
        x = linalg.inv(a)
        print(x)
def main():
    invmatrix()
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
    ‍‍‍‍‍
i wanna this with tensorflow